# how to test imports from building perl modules for conda?

Tags: python, perl, anaconda, conda

Whenever I try to build any perl recipes for conda ([example](https://github.com/bioconda/bioconda-recipes/tree/master/recipes/perl-module-build)), I get the following type of error:

```
$ conda build /home/conda/recipes/perl-module-build/
+ source /home/conda/miniconda2/bin/activate /home/conda/miniconda2/conda-bld/perl-module-build_1526324675451/_t_env
+ /home/conda/miniconda2/conda-bld/perl-module-build_1526324675451/_t_env/bin/python -s /home/conda/miniconda2/conda-bld/perl-module-build_1526324675451/test_tmp/run_test.py
  File "/home/conda/miniconda2/conda-bld/perl-module-build_1526324675451/test_tmp/run_test.py", line 2
    import Module::Build
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
TESTS FAILED: perl-module-build-0.4224-pl5.20.3_0
```

The contents of `run_test.py` are all import statements:

```
$ cat /home/conda/miniconda2/conda-bld/perl-module-build_1526324675451/test_tmp/run_test.py 
print("import: u'Module::Build'")
import Module::Build
```

The issue appears to be Python taking issue with the import statement, but I am not sure what I should be doing given that all the perl recipes I've found use the same kind of lines in their `meta.yaml` files (can see the full meta.yaml for the example above [here](https://github.com/bioconda/bioconda-recipes/blob/master/recipes/perl-module-build/meta.yaml)), i.e.

```
test:
    imports:
        - Module::Build
```

What am I missing? I am running conda-build version 2.1.10 and python2.7 on a Docker image with CentOS6 for reasons having to do with computing cluster compatibility. I can provide the image and commands if needed.

Comment: I may well be missing something here as I'm not familiar with *Conda*, and if so I'd be grateful if you enlightened me. I'm not clear how you expect to `import` Perl modules into Python code. I imagine that Python is getting upset about the colons in the module name. Package and module names should look like a standard Python identifier, perhaps with dot separators, and even digits are discouraged. Even if the statement was valid, Python doesn't stand a chance of understanding the Perl code in the `.pm` file.

Comment: For conda recipes you write a `build.sh` file which builds the software, and a `meta.yaml` file which has other information like what dependencies are needed and what tests to run. I didn't expect to import Perl modules into Python code, but for some reason the `meta.yaml` parsed testing Perl import statements as Python ones, which led to my question. I just found the answer however, it was a bug in conda that was fixed in later versions: https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues/1967

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you. Please would you write up your solution as an answer? You can then accept it yourself to mark the question as being resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-answer:

It was a bug in conda that was patched later on: https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues/1967

Instead of the `meta.yaml` parsing Perl import test statements as Perl, it was parsing them as Python.